# initWithContentsOfFile is leaking like crazy

Tags: objective-c, instruments, memory-leaks, initwithcontentsoffile

My application is completely leak-free (I think), but there is this one thing that supposedly leaks a whole lot. So here it is :

```
    mainPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    levelConfigPlistLocation = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",CATEGORY]];
    levelConfig = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:levelConfigPlistLocation];
```

And here is how I use it :

```
NSString *question = [[[levelConfig objectForKey:LEVELSETSTRING]objectForKey:LEVELSTRING]objectForKey:@"question"];

    questionLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:question dimensions:CGSizeMake(820.0f,360.0f) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"helvetica" fontSize:32.0f];
    questionLabel.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2-30 ,screenSize.height);
    questionLabel.color = ccc3(255,255,255);
    [self addChild:questionLabel z:5];
```

and:

```
NSString *answer = [[[levelConfig objectForKey:LEVELSETSTRING]objectForKey:LEVELSTRING]objectForKey:@"answer"];

    for (int i=0; i < [answer length]; i++) 
    { 
        NSRange r = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
        NSString *ichar = [answer substringWithRange:r]; 
        [characters addObject:ichar]; 
    }
```

And, in `-dealloc` I release it:

```
[levelConfig release];
```

Instruments shows me the following leaks:

[image: Screenshot Instruments]

Which, when I double-click, always shows the same line, namely:

[image: Screenshot Instruments 2]

which is obviously a leakage of levelconfig... but what can I do ?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone claimed their app was leak free.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're directly accessing your ivars, which you should not do. If you replaced this with `self.levelConfig =...`, then very likely your leaks would go away.

Most likely the particular block of code you've provided here is somewhere like `viewDidLoad` or some other place that can be called multiple times. Every time you do that, you're leaking the old contents of `levelConfig`. Using `self.` will fix that. Avoid direct access to your ivars except in `init` and `dealloc`.

Comment: Well, directly accessing ivars is appropriate and even recommended in an init method and in `-dealloc`. It's not clear where that line is called from. If not from an init method, then, yeah, it should be using accessors to make sure that any previous object pointed to by `levelConfig` is released before the variable is reassigned.

Comment: Agreed. As I noted "except in `init` and `dealloc`."

Comment: You've switched all your ivar accesses over to accessors (except in init and dealloc)? I wouldn't just do it in this one place. Consistent use of accessors are the absolute best way to avoid this kind of headache. You of course also need to audit every place you use levelConfig.